# Using SDL2 with SDL2_image on OSX 10.11 (CMake 3.3 within CLion 1.1)

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, sdl-2, clion

I'm following a couple of tutorials from reddit.com/r/limeoats to learn some game development in c++. I'm not experienced with CMake or CLion and have managed to google my way this far.

I had everything working up until I updated OSX to El Capitan (10.11). It seems that I can no longer use `#include "SDL2/SDL.h"` but instead need to use `#include "SDL.h"` Then it can find the SDL headers. The problem comes in when I also use `#include "SDL_image.h"` I get the following compiler error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework/Headers/SDL_image.h:27:10:
fatal error: 'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
         ^
```

Looking into the header file in my Frameworks folder, it has `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` but CMake is providing it as SDL.h for some reason after upgrading OSX to 10.11.

How do I get the SDL extensions to play nice with the updated header path? Or how do I get CMake to give me the old SDL2/SDL.h header path back?

Below is my CMakeLists.txt and I got the [FindSDL2.cmake](https://github.com/brendanwhitfield/collector/blob/master/cmake/FindSDL2.cmake#L50) (note the comment on line 50) and FindSDL2_image.cmake from [here](https://github.com/brendanwhitfield/collector/tree/master/cmake).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(Cavestory)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source/headers)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED >=2.0.0)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR})

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES "source/src/*.cpp")

add_executable(Cavestory ${SOURCE_FILES})

# One thread said this is all I should need to link SDL2
# but cannot get this to work at all
#target_link_libraries(Cavestory SDL2 SDL2_image)

#add_custom_command(TARGET Cavestory POST_BUILD
#        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
#        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/content $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:Cavestory>)
```

And my directory structure (if it helps)...

```
/Cavestory (root)
    CMakeLists.txt
    /bin
    /cmake
        FindSDL2.cmake
        FindSDL2_image.cmake
    /content
        /sprites
            **images**
    /docs
    /source
        /headers
           **header files**
        /src
           **code files**
```

Comment: Try to remove include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR}) because it is redundant. find_package will do it for you.

Comment: As an aside, you should include `SDL.h`, not `SDL/SDL.h`. [Source](https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQDevelopment#Do_I_.23include_.3CSDL.h.3E_or_.3CSDL.2FSDL.h.3E.3F).

Comment: @MinaKamel - Removed those lines, the compiler cannot find sdl.h nor SDL2/sdl.h - based on what i've read FindSDL.cmake sets those variables but does not call include_directories with them.

Comment: @zenith - that is what i'm doing and it works in *my code* but does not work for the SDL_image.h (which is not mine, and includes <SDL2/sdl.h> as I tried to state above.

Comment: It seems that current `SDL2_image` is incompatible with newest `SDL2`. Set `SDL2DIR` *environment* variable (note `$ENV{SDL2DIR}` in the `findSDL2.cmake`) to old SDL2 installation and make fresh configuration.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - Could you provide a source to where you got that? I did not change SDL2 versions between yesterday and today. Nor have I changed anything EXCEPT the OSX version... I cant figure out why that would affect this though. Furthermore, on my windows machine under cygwin i have this same version of SDL and SDL_image working together.

Comment: As for setting `SDL2DIR`, I have been found this from `findSDL2.cmake` file you provide: when it search `SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR`, it uses `find_path` with `HINTS` option contained `$ENV{SDL2DIR}`. That means if given variable is set, it will be tested for being include directory. As for incompatibility, I deduce that from your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel stupid... My CMakeLists.txt file is correct except i needed to add the following

```
target_link_libraries(Cavestory ${SDL2_LIBRARY} ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY})
```

instead of

```
target_link_libraries(Cavestory SDL2 SDL2_image)
```

This fixes the SDL linking issue from SDL_image.h; However, after updating to El Capitan, I can no longer reference SDL via `#include "SDL2/SDL.h"` and must use `#include "SDL.h"` -- while this is preferred, I'd like to know why/how this changed between OSX 10.10 and OSX 10.11.

Comment: Changing `target_link_libraries` cannot affect on include directories(linking comes *after* compiling sources). Probably, problem was in something else. In any case it is good that you have resolved it.

Comment: @Rob  Is there anything else you've tried that's outside this thread?  I saw the same behavior after upgrading to El Capitan, and followed this thread with no success.

Comment: I did not. I am including SDL in my code via `#include "SDL.h"` instead of `#include "SDL/SDL.h"` not sure why it changed between OSX versions, which is weird to me.