# How can I set up sdl for M1 mac to use with C

Tags: c, macos, sdl, apple-m1

I am trying to write a C program featuring the SDL2 library. I have installed SDL using homebrew using the below command:
brew install sdl2
I do not know what command to use to compile my code. I usually use gcc  but it generates this error in this case:

fatal error: 'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

I tried compiling with clang and got the same error.

Is there a special flag/argument I need to include to give the compiler the address to the library?

This is the code I am trying to compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(void)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
    {
        printf("error initializing SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("initialization successful!\n");

    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: C or C++, pick one? Also, search for existing questions like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using SDL2 with SDL2\_image on OSX 10.11 (CMake 3.3 within CLion 1.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33135856/using-sdl2-with-sdl2-image-on-osx-10-11-cmake-3-3-within-clion-1-1)

Answer (score 4):

To compile this, you must tell the compiler where the libraries to link and header files to include reside:

```
clang -v test.c -I/opt/homebrew/include -L/opt/homebrew/lib -lSDL2 -o test.o
```

Answer (score 1):

After donwloading the .dmg package available in https://www.libsdl.org/ and following the setup, that is, placing `SDL2.framework` in `/Library/Frameworks/` you can run the c or c++ file with the following command

```
 clang [file name] -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2
```

Which tells the compiler the location of the headers and frameworks necessary. Cheers!